# What are the spots on my lilac bush?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, diseases, fungus, lilac

I just had someone plant lilac bushes for me and this is what they look like.
[image]

They don’t seem healthy.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely just transplant shock. The roots have been cut, the tops probably left intact and the roots that are left have a problem keeping up with transpiration from the leaves, so the plant begins to prune itself and try to rebalance top and bottom.

Lilacs are very pH (acidity/basic) sensitive. "Lilacs love limestone" is a comment we often hear from gardeners. If the plants have been moved from a low acidity to a high acidity soil then there will be visible effects from the move and the most tender parts, the leaves, will be the first to show that the plant is not happy where it is. Possibly addition of lime would help but get a soil test done if the plants do not recover quickly.